# java signature "hash values do not match"

Tags: java, ssl, soap, digital-signature, x509certificate

I am trying to send an xml document to a remote server.  I sign the document using a keystore that contains a private key and certificate.  But when the remote server gets the xml, it responds with "hash values do not match".

Research on this error says that the xml document is being changed after it is signed.  My java code does not make any such changes after the signing, as far as I can tell.  I have also tried removing all the whitespace from the xml, just before signing, but that had no effect.

Here is part of the signature xml that is being generated:

```
    <SOAP-SEC:Signature SOAP:mustUnderstand="1">
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
          <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <Reference URI="#Body">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>yFfex/IpBJ4zrAFxJ5kkTKBrIR8=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>F9dnhEW/RN4IphLUfSu0kCJ/+0L6KtzJlxuptzWYL52su1/mfpnaQaqdHW/iJeLUL4PJZ47hxXwwMZj5y9GJMxnedz+XSu+4GJ5dwEY…
aqQTJg==</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <X509Data>
            <X509IssuerSerial>
              <X509IssuerName>CN=RapidSSL RSA CA 2018,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US</X509IssuerName>
              <X509SerialNumber>8986524346372316412121820876514917638</X509SerialNumber>
            </X509IssuerSerial>
            <X509Certificate>MIIFtTCCBJ2gAwIBAgIQBsK927DS8wePBQjvzVX9BjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBeMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChM…
YRtXpTI5y30r02yhghe//nMCL3MthO/gjEqGiLb1CxOncQ+j4A8+cfN+RR2fgA==</X509Certificate>
          </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
    </SOAP-SEC:Signature>
```

When the remote server tries to decode this value, it is apparently not coming up with the original signed version.  Note that Reference URI=”Body” means that only the section of xml that contains the Id=”Body” is being used to generate the DigestValue.

Here is the section of xml that contains “Id=Body”:

```
  <SOAP:Body Id="Body" xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <ProcessCreditApplication xmlns="http://www.starstandards.org/STAR">
      <ApplicationArea>
        <CreationDateTime>2019-12-09T18:26Z</CreationDateTime>
        <Destination>
          <DestinationNameCode>RO</DestinationNameCode>
        </Destination>
      </ApplicationArea>
      <DataArea>
        <oa:Process xmlns:oa="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis"/>
        <CreditApplication>
          <Header>
            <DocumentDateTime>2019-12-09T18:26Z</DocumentDateTime>
          </Header>
          <Detail>
            <CreditVehicle> 
             <Model>GRAND CHEROKEE</Model>
             <ModelYear>2015</ModelYear> 
            </CreditVehicle> 
          </Detail>
        </CreditApplication>
      </DataArea>
    </ProcessCreditApplication>
  </SOAP:Body>
```

Here is the java code to sign the xml.  It generates and then inserts the Signature block into the SOAP-SEC:Signature element shown in the example above:

```
    private void buildSignatureBlock5(String privateKeyPath, String publicKeyPath) {
    // Create a DOM XMLSignatureFactory that will be used to generate the signature.
    XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

    // Create a Reference to the enveloped document (in this case,
    // you are signing just the element with Id="Body", so a URI of "#Body" signifies
    // that), and also specify the SHA1 digest algorithm and the xml-exc-c14n# Transform.
    Reference ref = null;
    try {
        ref = fac.newReference
         ("#Body", fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null),
          Collections.singletonList
           (fac.newTransform
            ("http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#", (TransformParameterSpec) null)),
             null, null);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Create the SignedInfo.
    SignedInfo si = null;
    try {
        si = fac.newSignedInfo
         (fac.newCanonicalizationMethod
          (CanonicalizationMethod.EXCLUSIVE,
           (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null),
            fac.newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA1, null),
             Collections.singletonList(ref));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    // Load the KeyStore and get the signing key and certificate.
    KeyStore ks = null;
    try {
        ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(storage_path +"/keys/company.jks"), "changeit".toCharArray());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry = null;
    try {
        keyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry
            ("1", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("changeit".toCharArray()));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnrecoverableEntryException | KeyStoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();

    // Create the KeyInfo containing the X509Data.
    KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
    List x509Content = new ArrayList();
    String issuerName = cert.getIssuerX500Principal().getName();
    BigInteger serialNumber = cert.getSerialNumber();
    X509IssuerSerial issuer = kif.newX509IssuerSerial(issuerName, serialNumber);
    x509Content.add(issuer);
    x509Content.add(cert);
    X509Data xd = kif.newX509Data(x509Content);
    KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(xd));    

    // Create a DOMSignContext and specify the RSA PrivateKey and location of the resulting XMLSignature's parent element.
    Element envHeaderSig = (Element) document.getElementsByTagName("SOAP-SEC:Signature").item(0);
    DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(keyEntry.getPrivateKey(), envHeaderSig);

    // Create the XMLSignature, but don't sign it yet.
    XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);

    try {
        signature.sign(dsc);    //ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID Body
    } catch (MarshalException | XMLSignatureException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    removeWhitespaceFromSignature();
}

//hack to remove unwanted CR at the end of each line in SignatureValue and X509Certificate
private void removeWhitespaceFromSignature() {
    Element sig = (Element) document.getElementsByTagName("SignatureValue").item(0);
    String sigValue = sig.getTextContent().replaceAll("\r\n", "");
    sig.setTextContent(sigValue);

    Element cert = (Element) document.getElementsByTagName("X509Certificate").item(0);
    String certValue = cert.getTextContent().replaceAll("\r\n", "");
    cert.setTextContent(certValue);
}
```

I’m providing the XML to sign in the following line:

```
Element envHeaderSig = (Element) document.getElementsByTagName("SOAP-SEC:Signature").item(0);
```

But I don’t know how the subsequent “signature.sign” processes that data.  Does it remove whitespace?  Apparently, whatever it does results in the decoding algorithm on the remote server side producing different XML, creating a mismatch in the DigestValue (hash) it calculates.

Here is the java code used to send the soap request:

```
send(String xmlSoapString) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    OutputStreamWriter wr = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String result = "";
    try {
        URL connectionUrl = new URL(url);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) connectionUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);  
        connection.setDoInput(true);    

        //set connection properties - guessing at equivalents from PHP headers
        connection.setRequestProperty("accept","image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, */*");
        connection.setDefaultUseCaches(false);  // "cache-control: no-cache"
        connection.setRequestProperty("content-type","text/html");
        connection.setRequestProperty("pragma","no-cache");
        connection.setRequestProperty("time_stamp",timestamp_unix);
        connection.setRequestProperty("timestamp",timestamp);
        connection.setRequestProperty("SentTimeStamp",timestamp);
        connection.setRequestProperty("version","2.0");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-length",String.valueOf(documentToString(xml).length()));

        Map<String,List<String>> requestProperties = connection.getRequestProperties();
        String userCredentials = userId + ":" + dmsId;
        String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth); 
        setSoapHeader(connection);
        wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(xmlSoapString);    //send soap request to remote server
        wr.flush();      

        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
        }

        StringBuilder bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            bodyBuilder.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        result = String.valueOf( bodyBuilder.toString());
        System.out.println("Response=" +result);    

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (wr != null) {
            wr.close();
        }
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if ( connection != null ) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }   
    return result;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried the Validate.java example given in the official documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/java-xml-digital-signature-api-overview-and-tutorial.htm#JSSEC-GUID-E7E9239F-C973-4D05-AC3F-53F714C259DB.  I ran "java Validate signature.xml" and it failed with "Signature failed core validation
signature validation status: false
ref[0] validity status: false".  How are we supposed to get our stuff to work when we can't even get the simple official example to work?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got this to work.  It was very complicated.  Apparently the #body section was not being selected correctly.  Here is the code that got it right.

```
private void buildSignatureBlock() {
    // Create a DOM XMLSignatureFactory that will be used to generate the signature.
    XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

    // Create a Reference to the document (in this case, you are signing just the element with
    // Id="Body", so a URI of "#Body" signifies that), and also specify the SHA1 digest algorithm
    // and the xml-exc-c14n# Transform.
    Reference ref = null;
    try {
        ref = fac.newReference
                ("#Body", fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null),
                        Collections.singletonList
                                (fac.newTransform
                                        ("http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#", (TransformParameterSpec) null)),
                        null, null);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Create the SignedInfo.
    SignedInfo si = null;
    try {
        si = fac.newSignedInfo
                (fac.newCanonicalizationMethod
                                (CanonicalizationMethod.EXCLUSIVE,
                                        (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null),
                        fac.newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA1, null),
                        Collections.singletonList(ref));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Load the KeyStore and get the signing key and certificate.
    KeyStore ks = null;
    try {
        ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        ks.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/xml/project/keys/project.jks"), "password".toCharArray());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry = null;

    try {
        keyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry
                ("1", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("password".toCharArray()));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnrecoverableEntryException | KeyStoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();

    // Create the KeyInfo containing the X509Data.
    KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
    List x509Content = new ArrayList();
    String issuerName = cert.getIssuerX500Principal().getName();
    BigInteger serialNumber = cert.getSerialNumber();
    X509IssuerSerial issuer = kif.newX509IssuerSerial(issuerName, serialNumber);
    x509Content.add(issuer);
    x509Content.add(cert);
    X509Data xd = kif.newX509Data(x509Content);
    KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(xd));

    // Create a DOMSignContext and specify the RSA PrivateKey and location of the resulting XMLSignature's parent element.
    Element envHeaderSig = (Element) document.getElementsByTagName("SOAP-SEC:Signature").item(0);

    // Create the XMLSignature, but don't sign it yet.
    XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);

    try {
        Node envelope = document.getFirstChild();
        Node header = envelope.getFirstChild();
        DOMSignContext sigContext = new DOMSignContext(keyEntry.getPrivateKey(), header);
        // Need to distinguish the Signature element in DSIG (from that in SOAP)
        sigContext.putNamespacePrefix(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "ds");

        // register Body ID attribute   sigContext.setIdAttributeNS(getNextSiblingElement(header),"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/security/2000-12","id");
        signature.sign(sigContext);

    } catch (MarshalException | XMLSignatureException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ///VALIDATE the signature
    Element sigElement = envHeaderSig;
    DOMValidateContext valContext =
            new DOMValidateContext(cert.getPublicKey(), sigElement);
    Element envelope = getFirstChildElement(document);
    Element header = getFirstChildElement(envelope);
    valContext.setIdAttributeNS
            (getNextSiblingElement(header),
                    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/security/2000-12","id");
    boolean isValid = false;
    try {
        isValid = signature.validate(valContext);
    } catch (XMLSignatureException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Validating the signature... " +
            (isValid ? "valid" : "invalid"));
}
```

Here's a couple functions that pull the needed elements from the document for signature validation:

```
private static Element getFirstChildElement(org.w3c.dom.Node node) {
    org.w3c.dom.Node child = node.getFirstChild();
    while (child != null &&
            child.getNodeType() != org.w3c.dom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        child = child.getNextSibling();
    }
    return (Element) child;
}

public static Element getNextSiblingElement(org.w3c.dom.Node node) {
    org.w3c.dom.Node sibling = node.getNextSibling();
    while (sibling != null &&
            sibling.getNodeType() != org.w3c.dom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        sibling = sibling.getNextSibling();
    }
    return (Element) sibling;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be due to the remote server not using the same xml canonicalization approach(exclusive) that you are using. This can cause the hash to be computed on an xml that is syntactically different.